# Sublime Text 3 - show whitespace charcters

Tags: sublime-text

I'm trying to edit the Sublime Text 3 user preferences (Preferences > Settings) to get it to show all formatting characters (including whitespace). I believe the line

```
"draw_white_space": "selection"
```

has to be changed to

```
"draw_white_space": "all"
```

but I cannot edit the JSON file. I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Comment: Are you changing `user` or `default` settings file?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

To get your settings picked by sublime you have to edit the `Packages/User/Preferences.sublime-settings` file.

To access go to:

```
preferences > settings
```

The files will open into a *split form* with `default settings` which are *unalterable* on the left of sublime text, and the editable `user settings` on the right. Now add your settings there:

```
{
    "color_scheme": "Packages/Color Scheme - Default/Monokai.tmTheme",
    "font_size": 10,
    "ignored_packages":
[
    "Vintage"
],
    "save_on_focus_lost": true,
    "draw_white_space": "all"
}
```

This will override the `default settings` version of this option.

Comment: Hmm, still doesn't draw/show newlines.

Comment: @flow2k - well whitespace and newline are two different things.

Comment: @kta, it depends upon the context. In many encodings, such as XML, and all derived markup, newlines ARE whitespace. https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#NT-S  Another example is \S in regex. In fact it's pretty rare for newlines NOT to be considered as whitespace.